# Disable "Try It Out" in Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

This question has been asked a lot for different languages. After a substantial amount of (fruitless) browsing Im feeling rather dumb but, I'll ask anyway

This document refers to adding a Swagger plugin in what appears to be Javascript
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3725

I tried adding that code as an injected Javascript resource:

```
c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "MyProject.Scripts.swagger-plugins.js");
```

Code in the .js file is

```
const DisableTryItOutPlugin = function() {
    return {
        statePlugins: {
            spec: {
                wrapSelectors: {
                    allowTryItOutFor: () => () => false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

const DisableAuthorizePlugin = function () {
    return {
        wrapComponents: {
            AuthorizeBtn: () => () => null
        }
    }
}

SwaggerUI({
    plugins: [
        DisableTryItOutPlugin,
        DisableAuthorizePlugin
    ]
})
```

That achieved nothing and I have no idea where to go next.

Answer (score 20):

you can hide Try it out button in swagger **(using swashbuckle, C# dotnet core)** -

Affected Code Line -

```
c.SupportedSubmitMethods(new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SubmitMethod[] { }
```

Entire code sample - (Add inside configure method)

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/test/swagger.json", "test API");
                c.SupportedSubmitMethods(new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SubmitMethod[] { });
            });
```

This is worked because, we have used SubmitMethod enum which have following values inside that -

```
    public enum SubmitMethod
    {
        Get = 0,
        Put = 1,
        Post = 2,
        Delete = 3,
        Options = 4,
        Head = 5,
        Patch = 6,
        Trace = 7
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`NSwag.AspNetCore@13.16.1` and .Net 6.0:

```
app.UseSwaggerUi3(opts =>
{
    opts.EnableTryItOut = env.IsDevelopment();
});
```

I used this to only allow "try it out" for local development. You can set it specifically to `false` instead if you want it always off.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with these lines in the Configure method in the startup.cs file

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
              {
                  if (!env.IsDevelopment())
                     c.SupportedSubmitMethods(new SubmitMethod[] { });

                  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/swagger.json", "API");
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to directly disable/hide corresponding buttons:

```
$(() => {
    $('.tryitout').prop('disabled', true);
})
```

Comment: This doesn't stop anyone. You can just re-enable it via web console.

Answer (score 0):

This works in .Net 6.0 & Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.3.1

Note: Following sample only shows the new option to disable try-it-out button but not all the Swagger UI options used.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{       
    options.EnableTryItOutByDefault();
});
```

Comment: This removes the button by defaulting the documentation to show the 'Try it out' panel by default. It is the opposite of what the question intends to do, ie. remove the 'Try it out' button *and all its functionality*.