# VS ASP.NET Core Swagger: Always enable parameter fields without "Try it out"

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, visual-studio-2022

VS generates the following code in Startup.cs:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "project name v1"));
        }
```

So, it seems that the whole point of using the thing called Swagger is for testing the API during debugging. Then, why are the parameters field disabled by default and I have to click "Try it out" each time? Shouldn't the input fields be enabled by default? How should I modify the generated Startup.cs to enabling the parameters fields by default without pressing the Try button each time?

Comment: take a look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55914610/disable-try-it-out-in-swagger

Comment: @fmansour The answer only removes the Try button without enabling the parameters fields, making it impossible to debug the project. I need a way to "enable the parameters fields by default" and remove the Try button (which is optional).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method - `EnableTryItOutByDefault`

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.EnableTryItOutByDefault();
});
```

There won't be any Try Out button and parameters fields will be enabled by default.

Comment: It seems like the button exists, but clicked by default and become "Cancel". If I press the "Cancel" button, of course, it became "Try it out". I thought if I use this with the command that hide the button completely (as the comment in OP), I could achieve both, but that did not enable the fields, so I guess I have to choose one.